# How to prepend pandas data frames

Tags: pandas

How can I prepend a dataframe to another dataframe? Consider dataframe A:

```
b c d
2 3 4
6 7 8
```

and dataFrame B:

```
a
1
5
```

I want to prepend A to B to get:

```
a b c d
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

2 methods:

```
In [1]: df1 = DataFrame(randint(0,10,size=(12)).reshape(4,3),columns=list('bcd'))

In [2]: df1
Out[2]: 
   b  c  d
0  5  9  5
1  8  4  0
2  8  4  5
3  4  9  2

In [3]: df2 = DataFrame(randint(0,10,size=(4)).reshape(4,1),columns=list('a'))

In [4]: df2
Out[4]: 
   a
0  4
1  9
2  2
3  0
```

Concating (returns a new frame)

```
In [6]: pd.concat([df2,df1],axis=1)
Out[6]: 
   a  b  c  d
0  4  5  9  5
1  9  8  4  0
2  2  8  4  5
3  0  4  9  2
```

Insert, puts a series into an existing frame

```
In [8]: df1.insert(0,'a',df2['a'])

In [9]: df1
Out[9]: 
   a  b  c  d
0  4  5  9  5
1  9  8  4  0
2  2  8  4  5
3  0  4  9  2
```

Answer (score 5):

Achieved by doing

```
A[B.columns]=B
```

Comment: Surely this is appending, rather than prepending?

Comment: Technically yes, I'm appending B to A, or I'm prepending A to B. I didn't want to say append() because that would infer simply using .append, which does not get the output I wanted.